# no matches for kind "Profile" in version "kubeflow.org/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I install kubeflow and tried manual profile creation following to [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/multi-tenancy/getting-started/), but got this print

```
error: unable to recognize "profile.yaml": no matches for kind "Profile" in version "kubeflow.org/v1beta1"
```

How can I solve it?

Your valuable help is needed.

my resource is `profile.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kubeflow.org/v1beta1
kind: Profile
metadata:
  name: tmp_namespace   
spec:
  owner:
    kind: User
    name: example_01@gmail.com   

  resourceQuotaSpec:    
   hard:
     cpu: "2"
     memory: 2Gi
     requests.nvidia.com/gpu: "1"
     persistentvolumeclaims: "1"
     requests.storage: "5Gi"
```

> user infomation in dex:
>
> ```
> - email: exam_01@gmail.com
>   hash: $2a$12$lRDeywzDl4ds0oRR.erqt.b5fmNpvJb0jdZXE0rMNYdmbfseTzxNW
>   userID: "example"
>   username: example
> ```
>
> Of course I did restart dex
>
> ```
> $ kubectl rollout restart deployment dex -n auth
> ```

```
$ kubectl version --client && kubeadm version
```

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:"a43c0904d0de10f92aa3956c74489c45e6453d6e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:28:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.13", GitCommit:"a43c0904d0de10f92aa3956c74489c45e6453d6e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-17T18:27:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way.

If you see the message `no matches for kind "Profile" in version "kubeflow.org/v1beta1`, you may not have done the two necessary installs.

go  [kubeflow/manifasts](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests), and follow command to install `Profiles + KFAM` and `User Namespace`